# Why do I keep getting "invalid syntax" error?

Tags: python, syntax

```
import pygame,sys
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Magnifying Glasses")

size = (425,550)

lightcyan = (191,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
cyan = (127,255,255)
lightblue = (95,127,255)

titlefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",36)
subtitlefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",24)
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",12)

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    fadein = pygame.Surface(size)
    fadein.set_alpha(255)
    screen_Rect = screen.get_rect()

    spacing = 18

    title_Text = titlefont.render("NOW I SEE",1,black,lightcyan)
    title_TextRect = title_Text.get_rect(center = screen_Rect.center)
    title_TextRect.center = (title_TextRect.center)
    title_TextRect.top = 24

    underline = pygame.Surface((title_TextRect[2],2))

    fadein_Alpha = 255

    page = 4

    navigation_Y = title_TextRect.bottom + spacing
    button_Length = (size[0] - spacing - spacing) / 4
    button_Width = button_Length / 4
    button_Color = lightcyan
    button_LineColor = black
    LEFT = 1

    home_Rect = pygame.Rect(spacing,navigation_Y,button_Length,button_Width)
    background_Rect = pygame.Rect(home_Rect.right,navigation_Y,button_Length,button_Width)
    refraction_Rect = pygame.Rect(background_Rect.right,navigation_Y,button_Length,button_Width)
    interact_Rect = pygame.Rect(refraction_Rect.right,navigation_Y,button_Length,button_Width)

    home_Text = font.render("Home",1,button_LineColor)
    background_Text = font.render("Background",1,button_LineColor)
    refraction_Text = font.render("Refraction",1,button_LineColor)
    interact_Text = font.render("Interact",1,button_LineColor)

    home_TextRect = home_Text.get_rect(center = home_Rect.center)
    background_TextRect = background_Text.get_rect(center = background_Rect.center)
    refraction_TextRect = refraction_Text.get_rect(center = refraction_Rect.center)
    interact_TextRect = interact_Text.get_rect(center = interact_Rect.center)

    def home():
        global font

        line1 = font.render("    Have you ever looked at something small under a magnifying glass (for",1,black)
        line2 = font.render("example, bugs, small writing). The object (or objects) you are looking at",1,black)
        line3 = font.render("appear much larger than they actually are. This is because a magnifying glass",1,black)
        line4 = font.render("is composed of a lens. Lenses are curved pieces of glass that change the",1,black)
        line5 = font.render("appearance of objects when you look through them. Lenses come in two",1,black)
        line6 = font.render("varieties:",1,black)

        rect1 = line1.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,home_Rect.bottom + spacing))
        rect2 = line2.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect1.bottom))
        rect3 = line3.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect2.bottom))
        rect4 = line4.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect3.bottom))
        rect5 = line5.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect4.bottom))
        rect6 = line6.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect5.bottom))

        magnifyingglass = pygame.image.load("Magnifying Glass.png")
        magnifyingglass_Rect = magnifyingglass.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect6.bottom + spacing))

        convex = font.render("Convex: ",1,black)
        convex_Desc = font.render("(left)",1,black)
        convex_Rect = convex.get_rect(topleft = (magnifyingglass_Rect.right + spacing,rect6.bottom + spacing))
        convex_DescRect = convex_Desc.get_rect(topleft = (magnifyingglass_Rect.right + spacing,convex_Rect.bottom))

        line7 = font.render("Convex lenses are lenses that",1,black)
        line8 = font.render("are thickest near the centre.",1,black)
        line9 = font.render("When light enters this lens",1,black)
        line10 = font.render("it converges, then diverges.",1,black)
        line11 = font.render("The characteristics of the",1,black)
        line12 = font.render("image may vary.",1,black)

        rect7 = line7.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect6.bottom + spacing))
        rect8 = line8.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect7.bottom))
        rect9 = line9.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect8.bottom))
        rect10 = line10.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect9.bottom))
        rect11 = line11.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect10.bottom))
        rect12 = line12.get_rect(topleft = (convex_Rect.right,rect11.bottom))

        concave = font.render("Concave: ",1,black)
        concave_Desc = font.render("(right)",1,black)
        concave_Rect = concave.get_rect(topleft = (magnifyingglass_Rect.right + spacing,rect12.bottom + spacing))
        concave_DescRect = concave_Desc.get_rect(topleft = (magnifyingglass_Rect.right + spacing,concave_Rect.bottom))

        line13 = font.render("Concave lenses are lenses",1,black)
        line14 = font.render("that are thinnest near the",1,black)
        line15 = font.render("centre. When light enters",1,black)
        line16 = font.render("this lens, it diverges. The",1,black)
        line17 = font.render("image is always upright and",1,black)
        line18 = font.render("smaller than the object.",1,black)

        rect13 = line13.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect12.bottom + spacing))
        rect14 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect13.bottom))
        rect15 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect14.bottom))
        rect16 = line16.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect15.bottom))
        rect17 = line16.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect16.bottom))
        rect18 = line16.get_rect(topleft = (concave_Rect.right,rect17.bottom))

        rect7.left = concave_Rect.right
        rect8.left = concave_Rect.right
        rect9.left = concave_Rect.right
        rect10.left = concave_Rect.right
        rect11.left = concave_Rect.right
        rect12.left = concave_Rect.right

        convex_Img = pygame.image.load("Convex.png")
        concave_Img = pygame.image.load("Concave.png")

        convex_ImgRect = convex_Img.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,magnifyingglass_Rect.bottom + spacing))
        concave_ImgRect = concave_Img.get_rect(topright = (size[0] - spacing,magnifyingglass_Rect.bottom + spacing))

        screen.blit(line1,rect1)
        screen.blit(line2,rect2)
        screen.blit(line3,rect3)
        screen.blit(line4,rect4)
        screen.blit(line5,rect5)
        screen.blit(line6,rect6)

        screen.blit(magnifyingglass,magnifyingglass_Rect)

        screen.blit(convex,convex_Rect)
        screen.blit(convex_Desc,convex_DescRect)
        screen.blit(line7,rect7)
        screen.blit(line8,rect8)
        screen.blit(line9,rect9)
        screen.blit(line10,rect10)
        screen.blit(line11,rect11)
        screen.blit(line12,rect12)

        screen.blit(concave,concave_Rect)
        screen.blit(concave_Desc,concave_DescRect)
        screen.blit(line13,rect13)
        screen.blit(line14,rect14)
        screen.blit(line15,rect15)
        screen.blit(line16,rect16)
        screen.blit(line17,rect17)
        screen.blit(line18,rect18)

        screen.blit(convex_Img,convex_ImgRect)
        screen.blit(concave_Img,concave_ImgRect)

    def background():
        global font

        line1 = font.render("    Lenses were created from as early as 750 BC in the Middle East (The British",1,black)
        line2 = font.render("Museum, n.d.). In 1021, a man named Ibn Al-Haytham published the 'Book of",1,black)
        line3 = font.render("Optics', which described the use of a lens to magnify objects (Adam-Carr,",1,black)
        line4 = font.render("2010). The magnifying glass was later used in 1250, by English philosopher",1,black)
        line5 = font.render("Roger Bacon (Kashner, 2006).",1,black)

        rect1 = line1.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,home_Rect.bottom + spacing))
        rect2 = line2.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect1.bottom))
        rect3 = line3.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect2.bottom))
        rect4 = line4.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect3.bottom))
        rect5 = line5.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect4.bottom))

        line6 = font.render("    Magnifying glasses are capable of provide quick, weak magnification. When",1,black)
        line7 = font.render("compared to a microscope or telescope, a magnifying glass is lighter, simpler,",1,black)
        line8 = font.render("and easier to use; however, it can only magnify objects already visible to the",1,black)
        line9 = font.render("human eye. Another downside to the magnifying glass is its inability to",1,black)
        line10 = font.render("magnify objects further/larger than several metres. The use of a telescope is",1,black)
        line11 = font.render("more suitable for this role.",1,black)

        rect6 = line6.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect5.bottom + spacing))
        rect7 = line7.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect6.bottom))
        rect8 = line8.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect7.bottom))
        rect9 = line9.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect8.bottom))
        rect10 = line10.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect9.bottom))
        rect11 = line11.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect10.bottom))

        line12 = font.render("    Because of these traits, magnifying glasses may be used in fields of science",1,black)
        line13 = font.render("such as biology, forensic science, archaeology, and more.",1,black)

        rect12 = line12.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect11.bottom + spacing))
        rect13 = line13.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect12.bottom))

        line14 = font.render("Below are several common terms used to describe a convex lens:",1,black)
        line15 = font.render("Optical Centre (O): The point located in the centre of a lens",1,black)
        line16 = font.render("Principal Focus (F): The point at which oncoming light rays parallel to the",1,black)
        line17 = font.render("principal axis intersect",1,black)
        line18 = font.render("Secondary Focus (F'): The point symmetrical to F on the axis of symmetry",1,black)
        line19 = font.render("Axis of Symmetry: The line of symmetry drawn through the side view of a lens",1,black)
        line20 = font.render("Principal Axis: The line perpendicular to the axis of symmetry, that passes",1,black)
        line21 = font.render("through O",1,black)
        note = font.render("Note: ",1,black)
        line22 = font.render("2F and 2F' indicates the points that are 2× further from the lens than F",1,black)
        line23 = font.render("and F' respectively.",1,black)

        rect14 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect13.bottom + spacing))
        rect15 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect14.bottom + spacing))
        rect16 = line16.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect15.bottom))
        rect17 = line17.get_rect(topleft = (spacing + 96,rect16.bottom))
        rect18 = line19.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect17.bottom))
        rect19 = line21.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect18.bottom))
        rect20 = line22.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect19.bottom))
        rect21 = line23.get_rect(topleft = (spacing + 72,rect20.bottom))
        note_Rect = note.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect21.bottom + spacing))
        rect22 = line19.get_rect(topleft = (note_Rect.right,rect21.bottom + spacing))
        rect23 = line20.get_rect(topleft = (note_Rect.right,rect22.bottom))

        screen.blit(line1,rect1)
        screen.blit(line2,rect2)
        screen.blit(line3,rect3)
        screen.blit(line4,rect4)
        screen.blit(line5,rect5)

        screen.blit(line6,rect6)
        screen.blit(line7,rect7)
        screen.blit(line8,rect8)
        screen.blit(line9,rect9)
        screen.blit(line10,rect10)
        screen.blit(line11,rect11)

        screen.blit(line12,rect12)
        screen.blit(line13,rect13)

        screen.blit(line14,rect14)
        screen.blit(line15,rect15)
        screen.blit(line16,rect16)
        screen.blit(line17,rect17)
        screen.blit(line18,rect18)
        screen.blit(line19,rect19)
        screen.blit(line20,rect20)
        screen.blit(line21,rect21)
        screen.blit(note,note_Rect)
        screen.blit(line22,rect22)
        screen.blit(line23,rect23)
    def refraction():
        global font

        refraction_Img = pygame.image.load("Refraction.png")
        refraction_ImgRect = refraction_Img.get_rect(topright = (size[0] - spacing,home_Rect.bottom + spacing))

        line1 = font.render("    Refraction is the bending of light when it",1,black)
        line2 = font.render("passes from one medium (transparent",1,black)
        line3 = font.render("material) to another. You can experience",1,black)
        line4 = font.render("this phenomenon when you look through",1,black)
        line5 = font.render("water. By looking down in a swimming pool,",1,black)
        line6 = font.render("you can notice that the things you see are",1,black)
        line7 = font.render("actually deeper than they appear. When",1,black)
        line8 = font.render("light bounces of the object(s) in the water",1,black)
        line9 = font.render("and reaches the surface, the angle at which",1,black)
        line10 = font.render("it travels changes, and you see the light at",1,black)
        line11 = font.render("the changed angle.",1,black)

        rect1 = line1.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,home_Rect.bottom + spacing))
        rect2 = line2.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect1.bottom))
        rect3 = line3.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect2.bottom))
        rect4 = line4.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect3.bottom))
        rect5 = line5.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect4.bottom))
        rect6 = line6.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect5.bottom))
        rect7 = line7.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect6.bottom))
        rect8 = line8.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect7.bottom))
        rect9 = line9.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect8.bottom))
        rect10 = line10.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect9.bottom))
        rect11 = line11.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect10.bottom))

        line12 = font.render("    Light travels at different speeds in",1,black)
        line13 = font.render("different media. Depending on the 1st and",1,black)
        line14 = font.render("2nd media, light will refract towards/away from the normal. The normal is the",1,black)
        line15 = font.render("line drawn through the point that light refracts. It is perpendicular to the",1,black)
        line16 = font.render("border between the two media. If light travels slower in the 1st medium, it will",1,black)
        line17 = font.render("refract away from the normal (top). If light travels faster in the 1st medium, it",1,black)
        line18 = font.render("will refract towards the normal (bottom).",1,black)

        rect12 = line12.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect11.bottom + spacing))
        rect13 = line13.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect12.bottom))
        rect14 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect13.bottom))
        rect15 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect14.bottom))
        rect16 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect15.bottom))
        rect17 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect16.bottom))
        rect18 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect17.bottom))

        line19 = font.render("A lens is designed to control refraction to our advantage. The curvature is",1,black)
        line20 = font.render("created to make light converge/diverge during entry and exit of the lens. In the",1,black)
        line21 = font.render("case of a magnifying glass' convex lens, light is directed towards the principal",1,black)
        line22 = font.render("focus once when it enters the glass, and again when it exits the glass.",1,black)

        rect19 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect18.bottom + spacing))
        rect20 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect19.bottom))
        rect21 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect20.bottom))
        rect22 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect21.bottom))

        convexrefraction = pygame.image.load("Convex Refraction.png")
        convexrefraction_Rect = convexrefraction.get_rect(midtop = (size[0] / 2,rect22.bottom + spacing))

        screen.blit(refraction_Img,refraction_ImgRect)

        screen.blit(line1,rect1)
        screen.blit(line2,rect2)
        screen.blit(line3,rect3)
        screen.blit(line4,rect4)
        screen.blit(line5,rect5)
        screen.blit(line6,rect6)
        screen.blit(line7,rect7)
        screen.blit(line8,rect8)
        screen.blit(line9,rect9)
        screen.blit(line10,rect10)
        screen.blit(line11,rect11)

        screen.blit(line12,rect12)
        screen.blit(line13,rect13)
        screen.blit(line14,rect14)
        screen.blit(line15,rect15)
        screen.blit(line16,rect16)
        screen.blit(line17,rect17)
        screen.blit(line18,rect18)

        screen.blit(line19,rect19)
        screen.blit(line20,rect20)
        screen.blit(line21,rect21)
        screen.blit(line22,rect22)

        screen.blit(convexrefraction,convexrefraction_Rect)

    def interact():
        global font

        line1 = font.render("    To determine the qualities of an image, a ray is drawn from the top of the",1,black)
        line2 = font.render("object parallel to the principal axis (which refracts with respect to F) and",1,black)
        line3 = font.render("another ray is drawn from the top of the image through the optical centre",1,black)
        line4 = font.render("(which does not change direction). The top of the image is located where the",1,black)
        line5 = font.render("two rays intersect. We can then determine the size, attitude, location, and",1,black)
        line6 = font.render("type of the image produced.",1,black)

        rect1 = line1.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,home_Rect.bottom + spacing))
        rect2 = line2.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect1.bottom))
        rect3 = line3.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect2.bottom))
        rect4 = line4.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect3.bottom))
        rect5 = line5.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect4.bottom))
        rect6 = line6.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect5.bottom))

        location_Line = pygame.Surface((size[0] - spacing - spacing,2))

        location_Y = rect6.bottom + spacing
        location_Length = (size[0] - spacing - spacing) / 6
        location_Width = location_Length / 4
        location_Radius = spacing / 2
        location_Color = lightcyan
        location_LineColor = black
        LEFT = 1

        beyond2F_Rect = pygame.Rect(spacing,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)
        2F_Rect = pygame.Rect(beyond2F_Rect.right,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)
        between2FF_Rect = pygame.Rect(2F_Rect.right,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)
        F_Rect = pygame.Rect(between2FF_Rect.right,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)
        betweenFO_Rect = pygame.Rect(F_Rect.right,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)

        beyond2F_Text = font.render("←",1,location_Color)
        2F_Text = font.render("2F",1,location_LineColor)
        between2FF_Text = font.render("↔",1,location_LineColor)
        F_Text = font.render("F",1,location_LineColor)
        betweenFO_Text = font.render("→",1,location_LineColor)

        beyond2F_TextRect = beyond2F_Text.get_rect(center = beyond2F_Rect.center)
        2F_TextRect = 2F_Text.get_rect(center = 2F_Rect.center)
        between2FF_TextRect = between2FF_Text.get_rect(center = between2FF_Rect.center)
        F_TextRect = F_Text.get_rect(center = F_Rect.center)
        betweenFO_TextRect = betweenFO_Text.get_rect(center = betweenFO_Rect.center)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == LEFT:
                    mouse_Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if home_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 1
                    elif background_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 2
                    elif refraction_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 3
                    elif interact_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 4

        line7 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line8 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line9 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line10 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line11 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line12 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line13 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line14 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line15 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line16 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line17 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line18 = font.render("----",1,black)

        rect7 = line7.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect6.bottom))
        rect8 = line8.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect7.bottom))
        rect9 = line9.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect8.bottom))
        rect10 = line10.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect9.bottom))
        rect11 = line11.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect10.bottom))
        rect12 = line12.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect11.bottom + spacing))
        rect13 = line13.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect12.bottom))
        rect14 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect13.bottom))
        rect15 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect14.bottom))
        rect16 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect15.bottom))
        rect17 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect16.bottom))
        rect18 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect17.bottom))

        line19 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line20 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line21 = font.render("----",1,black)
        line22 = font.render("----",1,black)

        rect19 = line14.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect18.bottom + spacing))
        rect20 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect19.bottom))
        rect21 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect20.bottom))
        rect22 = line15.get_rect(topleft = (spacing,rect21.bottom))

        screen.blit(line1,rect1)
        screen.blit(line2,rect2)
        screen.blit(line3,rect3)
        screen.blit(line4,rect4)
        screen.blit(line5,rect5)
        screen.blit(line6,rect6)

        screen.blit(location_Line,(spacing,rect6.bottom + spacing - 1))

        screen.blit(line7,rect7)
        screen.blit(line8,rect8)
        screen.blit(line9,rect9)
        screen.blit(line10,rect10)
        screen.blit(line11,rect11)
        screen.blit(line12,rect12)
        screen.blit(line13,rect13)
        screen.blit(line14,rect14)
        screen.blit(line15,rect15)
        screen.blit(line16,rect16)
        screen.blit(line17,rect17)
        screen.blit(line18,rect18)
        screen.blit(line19,rect19)
        screen.blit(line20,rect20)
        screen.blit(line21,rect21)
        screen.blit(line22,rect22)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == LEFT:
                    mouse_Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    if home_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 1
                    elif background_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 2
                    elif refraction_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 3
                    elif interact_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_Pos):
                        page = 4

        if fadein_Alpha > 0:
            fadein_Alpha -= 3
            fadein.set_alpha(fadein_Alpha)

        screen.fill(lightcyan)
        fadein.fill(black)
        screen.blit(title_Text,title_TextRect)
        screen.blit(underline,(title_TextRect.left,title_TextRect.bottom))

        if page == 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,cyan,home_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,background_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,refraction_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,interact_Rect)
            home()
        elif page == 2:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,home_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,cyan,background_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,refraction_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,interact_Rect)
            background()
        elif page == 3:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,home_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,background_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,cyan,refraction_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,interact_Rect)
            refraction()
        elif page == 4:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,home_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,background_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_Color,refraction_Rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,cyan,interact_Rect)
            interact()

        pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_LineColor,home_Rect,2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_LineColor,background_Rect,2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_LineColor,refraction_Rect,2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,button_LineColor,interact_Rect,2)

        screen.blit(home_Text,home_TextRect)
        screen.blit(background_Text,background_TextRect)
        screen.blit(refraction_Text,refraction_TextRect)
        screen.blit(interact_Text,interact_TextRect)

        screen.blit(fadein,(0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

Whenever I run, IDLE tells me "invalid syntax" at the line `2F_Rect = pygame.Rect(beyond2F_Rect.right,location_Y,location_Length,location_Width)`. Apparently if I change every 2F in 2F_Rect, 2F_Text, and 2F_TextRect with something else like "apple" or "b2F" (anything random), I will not get the error. Could somebody explain to me why I will get a syntax error just because the variable has "2F" in its name???

I apologize I had to copy-paste the entire file

Comment: Before your next question, please read [mcve] to see why you don't have to copy-paste the entire file, and how to avoid it. In the current case, you could have written this 1-line python program: `2F_Rect = 'hello'`, confirmed it has the syntax error, and copy-pasted that short complete program instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables can't start with numbers.

You can see why by seeing Python's [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)